# jackson - Change the serializer for a POJO within a POJO being serialized

Tags: java, jackson, jsonserializer

I have a Jackson serializable object that contains other objects a few layers down. For certain cases (which can be annotated with `@JsonSerialize`), I want to change the serialization for that internal object. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

In the example below, `Request1` the `Foo` object throughout is serialized via default serialization, but in `Request2` all instances of `Foo` serialized with a custom serializer.

Request1 JSON:

```json
{
    id: "8c88e31c-f6da-4ce5-8c75-3cacd5cb6694",
    pojo: {
        foo: {
            value1: "abc",
            value2: "def"
        },
        bar: {
            other: {
                value1: "uvw",
                value2: "xyz"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Request2 JSON:

```json
{
    id: "8c88e31c-f6da-4ce5-8c75-3cacd5cb6694",
    pojo: {
        foo: [
            "abc",
            "def"
        ],
        bar: {
            other: [
                "uvw",
                "xyz"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Request1.java:

```java
public class Request1 {
    private UUID id;
    private MyPojo pojo;
}
```

Request2.java:

```java
public class Request2 {
    private UUID id;

    @JsonSerialize(using = MyPojoSerializer.class)
    private MyPojo pojo;
}
```

MyPojo.java:

```java
public class MyPojo {
    private Foo foo;
    private Bar bar;

    public static class Bar {
        private Foo other;
    }
}
```

Foo.java:

```java
public class Foo {
    private String value1;
    private String value2;
```

Serializer for `MyPojo`:

```java
public class MyPojoSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyPojo> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(final MyPojo value, final JsonGenerator gen,
            final SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
       
        // how to set custom serializer for Foo before serializing the MyPojo object???

        gen.writeObject(value);
    }

    private static class FooSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Foo> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(final Foo value, final JsonGenerator gen,
                final SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            gen.writeStartArray();
            gen.writeString(value.getValue1());
            gen.writeString(value.getValue2());
            gen.writeEndArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify:  Do you want to change the serialization for a class but ONLY for objects of that class which are properties of specific object types, or do you just want to have custom serialization for a specific class?  For the latter, you can obviously just add a custom serialize as you have done for `Request`

Comment: I want to change the serialization for all instances of class `Foo` within `Request`. So some places in my code I want to serialize `Request` as-is (`Foo` is serialized the default way) and some places I want to annotate `Request` with `@JsonSerialize(using = RequestSerializer.class`. so that all internal references to `Foo` use a custom serializer.

Comment: It's not easy to say without knowing more about your context (eg, what the different serialized forms look like and what conditions determine them), but could Jackson views help? [For reference](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)

Comment: I've updated the question with a lot more details, including the serialized forms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way to do this where you would actually register a custom serializer mid-serialization, but you can somewhat easily accomplish what you would like with this code:

```
public class MyPojoSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyPojo> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(final MyPojo value, final JsonGenerator gen,
            final SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {     
        gen.writeStartObject();
        provider.defaultSerializeField("bar", value.getBar(), gen);
        gen.writeFieldName("foo");
        serializeFoo(value.getFoo(), gen);
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    private void serializeFoo(final Foo value, final JsonGenerator gen) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartArray();
        gen.writeString(value.getValue1());
        gen.writeString(value.getValue2());
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

It's not ideal because you need to serialize each field manually (though the `provider` makes each field a one-liner), but maybe it will at least give you a way forward if you are stuck.

Comment: I've done this before, but unfortunately in this case my data model is significantly more complex than my example, with over 20 root fields going several levels deep. So this serialization would be really cumbersome to write let alone maintain. But I appreciate your answer.